# Run a javascript only on the child of the element that triggered it

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

I want to run a javascript only upon the child from the element that triggered it. I have tried to make a research but couldn't find a way to get an answer. I know this might be simple but I am new to java.

Here is the fiddle of my problem [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z33kk/20/).

What I want is that when I hover on the upper element, only its corresponding rating shows up, not both of them.
I have tried with find() without success

```
$('.product-image').hover(
  function() {
    $('.product-image').find('.ratings').css('opacity', '1');
  },
  function() {
    $('.ratings').css('opacity', '0');
  });
```

Thank you

Comment: CSS Animations would be so much easier. Your issue is the fact you are not selecting the element with the event, you pick all the elements again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `event.target` in your method body, which will give the element that triggered the `hover` event. Wrap it in `$()` to have jQuery context available.

```js
$('.product-image').hover(function(event){  
  $(event.target).next('.ratings').css('opacity', '1');
}, function(event){
  $(event.target).next('.ratings').css('opacity', '0');
});
```

Also updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z33kk/21/

Comment: I would use "function(e){ $(e.target).find('.ratings').css... instead of $(this)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is you do not select the element. You either need to change your code to use $(this) or $(evt.target) to get the element

How would I do it? With just CSS

```css
.product-image + .ratings {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease; 
  opacity: 0;
}

.product-image:hover + .ratings {
  opacity: 1;
}

.product-image {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ratings {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <div class="product-image"></div>
  <div class="ratings"></div>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <div class="product-image"></div>
  <div class="ratings"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this way! CSS over JS :)

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do it with CSS before. Great solution too!